# How to SetAddress when in a contact with no existing address

Tags: contacts, google-contacts-api

I am trying to update or add an Address in my contacts using a value in Google Sheet.
I am using this code (where address is the value in Google Sheet):

```
var AddressFields = contacts[i].getAddresses(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_ADDRESS);
AddressFields[i].setAddress(address);
```

It works when the contact I am trying to update has an Address field labeled HOME_ADDRESS.
But it does not work if the Address is labeled differently (WORK_ADDRESS for example) or if there is no existing Address

I tried to use the setLabel function to create an Address placeholder but it does not seems to work.

```
var addressFields = contacts[i].getAddresses();
addressFields[i].setLabel(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_ADDRESS);
```

Do you know how I could make sure it works in any situation?
Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

How about using nested-if? For example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++ {
    if (contacts[i].getAddresses(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_ADDRESS)) {
        address = contacts[i].getAddresses(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_ADDRESS;
    } else if (contacts[i].getAddresses(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_ADDRESS)) {
        address = contacts[i].getAddresses(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_ADDRESS);
    } else {
        address = '';
    }

    AddressFields[i].setAddress(address);
}
```

Comment: I think what you are proposing is actually getting the address from Google contacts right?
My issue is to find which Address field exists in Google contact and fill this with a value from a Google Sheet.
At the moment, if I am trying to fill the Home_Address but there is no address field labeled Home_Address, my script fails.

Comment: The idea was to check whether `HOME_ADDRESS` exists, if not, check if there is a `WORK_ADDRESS`. If all else fails, set to empty, so that at least there will be a fallback if there are no addresses available. I only tried to replicate this in a simple js file, so I'm not really sure how it would have been implemented on your case.